# "A dominant eigenvalue of a non-negative matrix has a non-negative eigenvector"

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the non-negative 3x3 matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 4 & 1 \\
  3 & 2 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}$. I've calculated the eigenvalues of this matrix, $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{5\pm \sqrt{17}}{2}, \lambda_{3} = 1$. Matlab confirms these values. This means $\frac{5 + \sqrt{17}}{2}$  would be the dominant eigenvalue $\lambda^{\star}$ (highest absolute value of all eigenvalues). When I compute the corresponding dominant eigenvector, I find $c\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  \frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}$. This contradicts "the dominant eigenvalue of a non-negative matrix has a **non negative** dominant eigenvector".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your eigenvector is wrong. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+4%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B3%2C+2%2C+1%7D+%7D).

Comment: Matlab says $x= [0, 0.8719, 0.4896]$ is a dominant eigenvector. You can confirm by comparing $Ax$ with $\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}x$

Comment: Thank you both! Dumb mistake that I made. Is there a specific function regarding the dominant eigenvector in matlab?

Comment: @Max You can just write [V D] = eig(A) and read the column of V corresponding to the column containing the largest eigenvalue in D. If you are only interested in the dominant eigenvalue, you can use the power method, which is only a few lines of code.